# Azure AD Account Linking Alexa Skills Kit

Tags: azure-active-directory, alexa-skills-kit, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm try to link my azure environment to Alexa. I'm using Auth Code Grant with HTTPBasic. After entering Authorization URI, Token URI, Client ID and Client Secret, the Link account page in alexa skill redirects to login.microsoftonline.com. After logging in, I'm redirected to skills.amazon.com which says Unable to link account to your skill. For the alexa endpoint, I'm using an Azure Function App. I'm able to get access tokens when testing on Postman. Has anyone encountered any similar issues? Is this a bug in alexa skills kit or Azure AD?

Comment: I had also problems with connecting alexa and azure. In the edit of my question https://stackoverflow.com/q/49998033/2575767 you can see which configuration finally solved my problem. Nate's answer helped me to find the problem.

Comment: See the link in @Nate's comment below. Also, its worth mentioning that I ran into problems with the refresh token not working and my authentication timing out after 90 mins. Please read my configuration/solution, if you run into this problem:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60716091/alexa-skill-with-azure-ad-b2c-auth-expires-after-an-hour

Answer (score 1):

Here is a blog post that walks through using an Azure Function to back an Alexa Skill and Azure AD. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2018/01/25/amazon-alexa-skills-authenticated-by-azure-active-directory-and-backed-by-an-azure-function/  It does need to be updated with the following:

- You can ignore the sections about the "front end" app registration.
- In Alexa account linking section update URLs to use login.microsoftonline.com instead of login.windows.net
- ClientId to be the Application Id of the "back end" app registration
- The ?resource= has to be set and has to be the same as the audience parameter for the JWT bearer options.
- The client secret (key) that is used can not be one that "Never Expires". Use a 1 or 2 year duration.